# C++ Programm calls superclass method instead of subclass method in factory pattern

Tags: c++, inheritance, factory-pattern

I'd like to build a factory for my Source-Plugins like that:

```
class PluginFactory {
public:
    PluginFactory(){};
    virtual ~PluginFactory(){};

    static MySource* getSourceById(int id, ParameterList& pList){
        switch (id){
            case 1:
                return new StringSource(pList);
            default:
                std::cout << "Unknown PluginId!" << std::endl;
                return nullptr;
        }

    }
};
```

`MySource` cannot be abstract like usual in the pattern because it will later be used in a template class.

When I call a method of the returned `MySource*` I get the method of the superclass `MySource` instead of the overridden method of the subclass `StringSource`.

Any ideas how to fix this?

EDIT:

I declared the superclass method as vritual:

```
MySource{
    ...
    virtual std::streamsize read(char* s, std::streamsize n){
    ...
    }
};
```

I added the override command to the subclasses' read-Method:

```
class StringSource: public MySource {
    ...
std::streamsize read(char* s, std::streamsize n) override
{
    ...
}
```

};

But it still uses the superclass method. There has to be another reason...

Btw. I put the Source-Class into a boost::iostream::filtering_istream like this:

```
MySource* source = PluginFactory::getSourceById(1, pluginList[0].second);
boost::iostreams::filtering_istream in;
in.push(*source);
```

So I don't call the read-method myself.

Comment: Please show us the code where you actually return the source, and try to call its method.

Comment: I don't call the method myself. I push the Source-Class into a boost::iostream::filtering_istream and there the read-Method is called. See edit above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
in.push(*source);
```

According to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/filtering_stream.html#policy_push), this will copy the argument. Since your base class is copyable and not abstract, you encounter the *slicing problem* where only the base sub-object is copied.

You should be able to fix it by passing a reference wrapper instead:

```
in.push(std::ref(*source));
```

I would suggest that you make the base class abstract (or at the very least uncopyable), to prevent the possiblity of slicing. I don't understand your reason for not making it abstract; but whatever requires it to be concrete sounds scary and error-prone.

**UPDATE**: Since you made it concrete just so you could pass it to this function, you should make it abstract again, and pass a reference wrapper instead.

Comment: It is very scary... in.push() needs a concrete class because it will be used in a template and templates do not accept abstract classes. Is there a solution to insert the abstract class into in-push()?

Comment: @schindi: Yes there is. Use a reference wrapper, as suggested in my answer and the linked documentation.

Comment: You mean I can use the abstract class if I use the reference wrapper? Btw. I get an error that ref is not a member of std although I included <functional>.

Comment: @schindi: Yes. The reference wrapper is a small, copyable object containing a reference to your object, which can be used as if it were an actual reference to it. So the stream will take a copy of that and, using it, call functions on your object (with the correct type), with no attempt to copy that.

Comment: @schindi: "ref is not a member of std" - that's weird. Perhaps your library implementation doesn't support it yet, in which case you could use `boost::ref` instead.

Comment: Thx Mike. It works with boost::ref and with abstract classes. It's a relieve that I can implement the Abstract Factory correctly with your help.

Answer (score 0):

> When I call a method of the returned MySource* i get the method of the superclass MySource instead of the overridden method of the subclass StringSource.

I'm not sure this will work (without seeing any relevant code), but it sounds like you need to declare your superclass method (the one you call) as `virtual`, so that the compiler knows to run the overridden version (in this case, of `StringSource`), rather than the superclass version.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @TemplateRex That too :D but really, can't think of any other reason why the superclass method is running, so maybe I'm right

Comment: The method was declared virtual from the beginning. See edit above.

Answer (score 0):

The method in `MySource` that you call must be `virtual` otherwise, the one in the derived class doesn't override but, instead, hides it. For instance,

```
class Base {
public:
            void foo() const { std::cout << "Base::foo()\n"; }
    virtual void bar() const { std::cout << "Base::bar()\n"; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void foo() const { std::cout << "Derived::foo()\n"; } // hides Base::foo
    void bar() const { std::cout << "Derived::bar()\n"; } // overrides Base::bar
};

Derived d;
Base& b = d;

d.foo(); // outputs Derived::foo()
b.foo(); // outputs Base::foo()
b.bar(); // outputs Derived::bar()
```

If you're using C++11, I would advise to use the override keyword in the declaration of `Derived::bar()`:

```
void bar() const override { std::cout << "Derived::bar()"; }
```

More precisely, you should use `override` in the declaration of all derived methods that are meant to override the one in the base class. If you make a mistake and the method in the derived class doesn't override any method in the base, then the compiler will raise an error.

Herb Sutter explains the issues [here](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/22/gotw-5-solution-overriding-virtual-functions/).

**Update:** After the OP's addition of more information.

Another possible reason for the issue is as follows. If the base class is copied (e.g. when it's passed to a function by value), then the copy looses information on the dynamic type. For instance, reconsider the example above and these functions:

```
void call_bar_pass_by_value(Base x) {
  x.bar(); 
}

void call_bar_pass_by_reference(const Base& x) {
  x.bar();
}
```

Then, calling them with `b` gives:

```
call_bar_pass_by_value(b);     // outputs Base::bar()
call_bar_pass_by_reference(b); // outputs Derived::bar()
```

I'm not familiar with Boost.Iostreams but looking at the reference documentation of `filtering_stream::push()` [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/filtering_stream.html) we can see that this function does take its argument by reference. Hence, the problem that I just described doesn't happen here. However, this function might call another one which call another one ... and one of them might make take the argument by value (or make a copy of it).

The OP states that "*MySource cannot be abstract like usual in the pattern because it will later be used in a template class*". This suggests that an attempt to copy the object is made.

I don't know what to advise now but just to test my theory above (it doesn't solve the issue) I would temporarily make `MySource`'s copy constructor `protected` to see whether Boost.Iostreams tries to copy `MySource`. If so, then the code will fail to compile.

Comment: I added some code above... My method is declared virtual and I added the override command. Changed nothing so far...